# Show items ArrayList with dynamic length

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have multiple `ArrayList` that contain 0 or 1 or 2 or 5 item .I need to show these items to user, witch way is better ? I create `TextView` programmatically or use from `recyclerView` for show ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few pros and cons of `recyclerView`

Pros:

```
· integrated animations for adding, updating and removing items
· enforces the recycling of views by using the ViewHolder pattern
· supports both grids and lists
· supports vertical and horizontal scrolling
```

Cons:

```
· adds complexity
```

If you're sure that

```
· There won't be more then 5 elements ever in future
· You don't need integrated animations for items
· You don't need to edit each item in the list
· You don't need to change the appearance of grid vs list dynamically
```

Then you should definitely prefer not using `RecyclerView`. It adds complexity and you you'll have the ease to play with each `itemView` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Upto 5 element, there will be no scrolling right. So better create `textview` for that.
If screen have scrolling, then `recyclerview` will make sense because it will hold items in memory which are currently showing in screen

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned only five items use recycler view if you want to add extra items also it will be easier